# Are UNIQUE indices case sensitive in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, key, unique, case-sensitive

Are indices *(indexes)* defined as UNIQUE case sensitive in MySQL?

Comment: As per popular demand, maybe you should update the chosen answer.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It depends on the [collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html) of the field - if it's `ci` (case insensitive) or `cs` (case sensitive). The unique index would apply accordingly.

Answer (score 27):

You can make a column case-sensitive by using this syntaxis.
the unique index also will be case-sensitive.

> ALTER  TABLE tbl_name MODIFY 
>   col_name column_definition 
>   [CHARACTER SET charset_name] 
>   [COLLATE collation_name]

Example:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `tablename` MODIFY
`column` VARCHAR(100) 
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

**Note:** utf8_bin compares strings by the binary value of each character in the string.

Tested on Msql 5.5.X