# mysql returns duplicate error for primary key

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, primary-key, uniqueidentifier

I have a primary key for a field called "key", and I have a script that auto uploads images with a different 'key' value, such as a, then b, then c, ect

After a while, it will go from z, to A, to B, to C, then after Z it will go: aa, ab, ac.. ect.

It is saying that a and A are the same entry, when they are not. I will probably also get this error with the keys aa and AA, how can I fix this? How can I set the primary key to accept different case letters, as it is currently thinking a and A are the same thing.

Comment: The MySQL collation is currently set to _ci, which means "Case Insenitive" - you need to change that.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are UNIQUE indices case sensitive in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463764/are-unique-indices-case-sensitive-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table to set collation to case sensitive, 
ex:
utf8_unicode_cs : case sensitive
and
utf8_unicode_ci : case insensitive

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_cs
```