# Spring Boot: How to find name by a case sensitive parameter in a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, dynamic

**I make simple database of names.** There are only three names: **A**d**a**m , **A**rnold and M**a**tin. And  I want  to get all names that  contains letter **"a"**.
I have in my repository this method:
Let String letter = "a";

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE name LIKE %:letter%", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameLike( @Param("letter") String letter);
```

**It returns all names(List of  names)**, because **it find** some **"a" or "A"** in all of names. But I want to find only names that contains **exactly lower case "a"**.
This  query works in the Workbech wery well:
`SELECT * FROM person WHERE name LIKE BINARY '%a%';` 
But this code returns empty(null) List.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE   name  LIKE BINARY '%:letter%'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameLike( @Param("letter") String letter);
```

I dont know how to link the variable letter to the  query. Thank you for  any ideas.
PS:How to make SQLinjection protection in  this  case if the  variable letter is wrapped in "%" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE   name  LIKE BINARY '%:letter%'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameLike( @Param("letter") String letter);
```

you are looking for names that contain the String ':letter', try

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE   name  LIKE BINARY CONCAT('%',:letter,'%')", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameLike( @Param("letter") String letter);
```

And using Query-annotation there is no chance of SQL-injection.

By using the right collation you decide on table creation wether queries are case sensitive or case insensitive, see [Are UNIQUE indices case sensitive in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463764/are-unique-indices-case-sensitive-in-mysql)

Comment: Hi Turo! Your  code works  perfectly! Thank you for your answer and for the collation tip!

Answer (score 0):

Change *BINARY* to *lower*. It specifies you want a lower-case.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE name LIKE lower '%:letter%'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameLike( @Param("letter") String letter);
```

As a tip, I wouldn't use 'jpql', if you can take advantage of spring-data, and you don't have to writte the query:

```
List<PersonEntity> findByLetterContaining(String letter);
```

Doc: [JPQL Like Case Insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178520/jpql-like-case-insensitive)

Comment: Hi Adolin! I chose  bad example, String letter = "Aa" is much better. Concat operator solves my  trouble. Thank you very much!